# Rcpp dataframe not contextually convertible to bool

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

How would you normally handle default values when using dataframes (from Rcpp)?

Here is what I've attempted:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::DataFrame FindFormula(Rcpp::DataFrame(masslist),Rcpp::DataFrame(params)=NULL
  ,Rcpp::DataFrame(isotope)=NULL) {

  // access masslist by column
  Rcpp::NumericVector mass = masslist["exp mass"];
  Rcpp::IntegerVector  mag = masslist["intensity"];

  // default params, if no entry
  if (params==NULL)
  {
    // access params by column
    Rcpp::StringVector param = params["value"];

    // assign param variables (string to value)
    double tol = std::stod(param[0]);
    int charge = std::stoi(param[1]);
  }
  else
  {
    // default params
    double tol = 0.4;
    int charge =   0;
  }
```

The params==NULL expression is where I get the error.  This seems to work if I define params as an int or array.  I haven't written much C++ and am new to Rcpp, so I'd appreciate anyone who knows more about dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of syntax issues worth pointing out in your code. First, `NULL` has a *very* [different meaning in C/C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL) than it does in R - don't use it in the way that you did above. You can use `R_NilValue` in your Rcpp code to represent R's `NULL`. Additionally, your function parameters aren't declared correctly. Syntactically, this statement -

```
Rcpp::DataFrame(masslist)
```

is calling the constructor / copy constructor for the `DataFrame` class on (presumably) another `DataFrame` object named `masslist`, but that's not what you want and it would not compile anyways. Your function signatures (broadly speaking) need to be more like

`ReturnType function_name(ParamType1 param1, ParamType2 param2, ...)`

or, with default arguments,

`ReturnType function_name(ParamType1 param1 = p1, ParamType2 param2 = p2, ...)`

where `p1` and `p2` are actual values, not variables.

---

In your case, I really think it's much simpler to write an Rcpp function that *does not* have default arguments, and call it from a simple wrapper function in R that specifies defaults. For example,

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::DataFrame FindFormulaCpp(Rcpp::DataFrame masslist_,
                             Rcpp::DataFrame params_,
                             Rcpp::DataFrame isotope_) {
  // do whatever

  return Rcpp::DataFrame::create(Rcpp::Named("Result") = Rcpp::rnorm(5));
}


/*** R

masslist <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 6:10)
params <- data.frame(a = rnorm(5), b = 1:5)
isotope <- data.frame(e = letters[1:5])

RFindFormula <- function(arg1 = masslist, arg2 = params, arg3 = isotope) {
  FindFormulaCpp(arg1, arg2, arg3)
}

R> RFindFormula()
# Result
# 1  0.84583003
# 2 -0.65687178
# 3 -1.05891172
# 4 -0.06872972
# 5 -0.19695890

*/
```

---

However, if you *insist* on handling this from C++, you could do something to this effect:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

struct my_defaults {
  Rcpp::DataFrame masslist, params, isotope;
  my_defaults() {
    masslist = Rcpp::Environment::global_env()["masslist"];
    params = Rcpp::Environment::global_env()["params"];
    isotope = Rcpp::Environment::global_env()["isotope"];
  }
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::DataFrame FindFormula(Rcpp::DataFrame masslist_ = R_NilValue,
                            Rcpp::DataFrame params_ = R_NilValue,
                            Rcpp::DataFrame isotope_ = R_NilValue) {
  Rcpp::DataFrame masslist, params, isotope;
  my_defaults defaults;

  if (masslist_.size() == 0) {
    masslist = defaults.masslist;
  } else {
    masslist = masslist_;
  }
  // likewise for the others
  return masslist;
}
```

---

It's not necessary to define your default arguments in a `struct` like I did above, you could just as well call, e.g. `masslist = Rcpp::Environment::global_env()["masslist"];` inside your function, but the former approach feels a little more organized IMO. Regardless, I would strongly recommend taking the first approach if at all possible.

Comment: Another nice and patient answer-- well done, @nrussell